# Getting error when uploading Cordova app into Testflight app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, cordova

I am trying to upload the Cordova app, into TestFlight. CFBundleShortVersionString is 3.4.1 and CFBundleVersion is 0.0.1. However, I am getting this error:

> The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value

I have researched this issue, and tried updating the CFBundleShortVersionString. Also, I tried by clearing all issues and with a clean build folder but it is still showing the same error.

I want to release the application into TestFlight.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide the full details of the error?  I suspect that it will say more than you have shown.

Comment: after review and accept the updated license agreement issue is fixed